# Sending email with Django using Gmail not working

Tags: django, gmail, smtplib

I'm new to Django and I want to send the email through my Django server using my Gmail account but unfortunately, I'm getting an error while sending emails even though I've put all credentials correctly there is one thing more in my Gmail account which is "less secure apps" that has to be enabled but this feature is no longer available in Gmail so now how can I send the emails in Django?

`error while sending the email`

```
b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f14-20020a05600c4e8e00b0039c5642e430sm4688852wmq.20 - gsmtp'
```

Answer (score 7):

Since May 30 2022 the less secure apps feature has been disabled. Now, to let 3rd party apps access gmail you must generate an App password and to generate an app password you must first enable 2-factor authentication for your account:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Once you have the app password you can simply replace your host account password with the app password:

```
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<app_password>'
```

You can find the complete email integration process wonderfully explained here: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/12-Password-Reset/django_project

Answer (score 0):

im looking forward for an answer too, as i am experiencing the same problem.

In the meantime, i had to change the email provider to another company, for me it worked with mailjet, they have a free plan and no card info needed, hope this helps you!