# How to fix django timeout error when sending email

Tags: django, backend, session-timeout, django-email, django-errors

I'm trying to make a simple django app that sends an email to a user, but every time i try to run the program, i get an error
'TimeoutError at /automail2/success
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

this happens after a couple seconds of loading after the email address has been submitted. Here's a github link to the code

https://github.com/Taterbro/automail

I'm fairly new to coding and the stackoverflow community, so any help would be appreciated.

tried to send an email using django
expected the code to send an email
the code timed out while trying to send the email

Comment: In **index.html** change `<form action='success' method="post">` to `<form action='{% url "success" %}' method="post">`.  Second, on stackoverflow you should post *code*, not a github.

Comment: @raphael oh, i'm sorry, i didn't know. Do i post the whole code? How do i go about doing that, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Also, after changing success, i got a different error instead 

'ConnectionRefusedError at /automail2/success
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Answer (score 0):

**Fix the timeout error**

As I noted in the comments,your timeout error was caused because the HTML template was using the wrong string for the `action`.  You can't use the name of the url path as the `action`, you need to have Django generate it when it renders the page:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!-- change -->
<form action='success' method="post">

<!-- to -->
<form action='{% url "success" %}' method="post">
```

**Fix the connection refused error**

Here the problem is not with your **views.py** code or your template, rather with the settings you use in **settings.py** and the way you have your email set up.

*I have tried your code, and it works fine*, but you need to change your gmail settings, and use those settings for your **settings.py**.  As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540809/10951070), you have to generate an *app password* if you want to use gmail to send emails in Django.  [Here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/gmail-app-passwords-what-they-are-how-to-create-one-and-why-to-use-them/) is a tutorial on how to do that.

**How to post a question on Stack Overflow**

To answer your other comment question, you should post *code*, not images of code, or in your case a GitHub link.  Here is a [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10951070) that explains *why* and also explains *how* to post code.  In your specific case it would be helpful if your edit your question to include the relevant **views.py**, **urls.py**, **settings.py** and the **index.html** template files.